# xkb: make ctrl+backspace behave as delete

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

How can I map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to behave as <kbd>Delete</kbd> key with `xkb`? I can remap a single key on `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` but can't figure out how to do the combination. My OS is Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Does [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/585300/how-to-make-control-j-works-as-return-without-control-bit-set-using-xkb-and#587678)'s answer work for you?

Comment: @user1717828 Not really, the config is just too cryptic, I need a more specific answer.

Comment: Also asked on Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627310/

Comment: I thought this might work with `xmodmap`, but is does not.  Apparently (and this is new to me, since I never needed or tried this) Ctrl cannot be used as a modifier which changes the character a key generates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As *Gilles* pointed out in a comment, you can do it with `xkb` if you change the type of `BKSP` key to control-modifiable.

Example: if I edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and under:

```
include "pc(editing)"
include "keypad(x11)"
```

change this line:

```
key <BKSP> {   [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ]   };
```

to:

```
key <BKSP> {
    type="PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]=  [ BackSpace, Delete ]
};
```

then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> behaves as <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: I've done this change, deleted `/var/lib/xkb/server-*` files, rebooted and the keyboard was not responding, couldn't even log in. I've reverted the change by booting from a live USB. What could be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault - missed the semicolon at the end. It works.