# Will booting ubuntu in recovery mode use default keyboard layout?

Tags: ubuntu, console, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have a chromebook with Ubuntu 15.04 and I need to customize some of my keyboard keys in xkb. Unfortunately while doing so I managed to disable my keyboard and needed to boot from live USB to revert the changes ([xkb: make ctrl+backspace behave as delete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205226/xkb-make-ctrlbackspace-behave-as-delete))

My question is: will booting in recovery mode use a default keyboard layout, so that in the event I mess up my xkb settings again I can just fix them?