# Is there a better way to bind keyboard shortcut with a keystroke

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

What I want to achieve is, if I press a keyboard shortcut, I get a keystroke. For example if I press `ctrl+j`, I will type the `down` key. I want this to work almost everywhere.

I know this can be done in most desktops by binding a keyboard shortcut to a `xdotool key [the key]` command. For example, on my xfce desktop, I can do that in the keyboard settings page. However, this solution seems buggy. For example, when I mapped `meta+t` to `a` for testing purposes, sometimes get `t` instead of `a`. Also, holding the keyboard shortcut does not simulate holding the keystroke. For example, if I held the `ctrl+j` in our first example, I only get one `down` key instead of a continuous `down` key.

On KDE, you can actually set a custom keyboard shortcut that sends keyboard input. And this works very well. Holding the shortcut also works. However, I wonder if this can be done in other environments.

I am not a programmer (although using linux for over a year now has taught me a lot of basic coding skills), so I wonder if there are other tools out there that I missed when I was searching around.

Comment: You can modify your keyboard layout with xkb. Try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205277) but instead of `BKSP` use `AC07` for `j`.

Comment: @Devon, Thanks! Looks promising! I will test it out when I got the time. Been really busy.